# Empty caroussel loaded using ng-view

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a little example with a simple responsive caroussel that works as expected.

```
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <header>header</header>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container fill" style="padding: 0px;">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item">
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/images/image2.jpg');">
                            <div class="container">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/images/image1.jpg');">
                            <div class="container">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/1024x700/CC1111/FFF');">
                            <div class="container">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-center">
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <footer>@Copyright</footer>
</div>
```

The matter is that when I bind it using angular, the images are not being displayed.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <header>
  </header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px;">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

And here is the code in my app.js file (the carousel is defined in the main.html file) :

```
var app = angular
.module('webappApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'main'
    })
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'about'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});


app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, $location) { 
  $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) { 
    return viewLocation === $location.path();
  };
});
```

I have no errors in the developer console, and in the network calls, the images are called and found. This it the output I have (only the controls are visible) :

[image]

Comment: If you are having problems with the angular, shouldn't you include it in your question?

Comment: yeah sorry was editing my question to paste the code

Comment: I found that if I add       .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }, then the image appears, but I don't understand why, if anyone has an idea

Answer (score 1):

To use ngView you need to have Routes set up. You didn't post any of your app JS code so it's hard to see where it might have gone awry, but generally the approach to do what I think you're asking would be:

1. Cut out the content for your carousel and put it in a separate .html file (called a "partial"). Make sure to leave out the footer and other elements that are part of your page "skeleton" and just put the content for your carousel into the partial
2. Add ngRoute to your app
3. Define routes ( in app.config() ). In your case, if it's just one page you'd likely use the ".otherwise" function on the RouteProvider and set the templateUrl to your partial html file
4. When route resolves, the partial is loaded into ngView (which can be an element, or an attribute of another element)

Without seeing your code it's tough to tell where you're having trouble, but my guess is that you're just trying to use ngView without routes; easy mistake to make.

Comment: I edited my question with the routes I have set up, the weird thing is that it was working but I changed my caroussel to make it responsive, and since that moment, the images are not loading anymore

Comment: It's still hard to see what you've got going... is your Carousel rendered by jQuery? This has classic symptoms of running a bunch of jQuery code before the Route / View is totally loaded. Have you tried deferring your Carousel initialization to something like $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess')? Using that and a $timeout() would likely solve it if it's just an issue with jQuery getting ahead of the rendering.

Comment: I was thinking that could be the problem but I can't understand why the following code works (my older version of the carousel and not the one I pasted above) : https://jsfiddle.net/11zx1zLp/

Comment: Ahhh ok - so your carousel is Bootstrap.js based (based on that Fiddle) - and the way Bootstrap's JS library works is based on jQuery's $(function(){ }) syntax where it loads all the jQuery when the page is finished loading - meaning it expects the DOM to be complete when it loads. This happens LONG before the RouteProvider has a chance to render into ngView. 

In your controller, try adding $timeout as an injector, and then:

    $timeout(function() {
         $("#myCarousel").carousel({ options ... });
    }, 3000);

Note: The 2nd parameter I set to 3000 (3s) so you can see it render after.

Comment: There is something really weird that I can't explain. When I load the carousel I showed you with the jsFiddle, it works as expected. But when I replace the images by background-images, it stops working. Changing that shouldn't affect the loading of jquery, should it?

Comment: Depends... The Bootstrap.js carousel might need actual images so that it can size the slides appropriately. Try setting a min-height on your slides and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. I had to set the height of the div :

```
  <div class="main">
      <div ng-view="" style="height:100%"></div>
  </div>
```